# Apache2 loop redirect on a App installed in a subfolder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I try to install my Symfony 4 app on a subfolder (on a "dev server") but I have some problems with the apache2 configuration (I'm complete noob with apache)

So here is my structure
My app is installed in `/var/www/html/rapp/`
I have an apache config file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/rapp.conf`with the following content

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/rapp/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/rapp/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /rapp/

            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L,NC]

        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/project>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    # optionally disable the RewriteEngine for the asset directories
    # which will allow apache to simply reply with a 404 when files are
    # not found instead of passing the request into the full symfony stack
    <Directory /var/www/html/rapp/public/bundles>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine Off
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/rapp/public/build>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine Off
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

On my app root folder (so `/var/www/html/rapp/`), I have an .htaccess file with the following content to redirect `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/rapp/` url to my app

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /rapp/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have no .htaccess in `/var/www/html/rapp/public` because it must be handle by the `Directory` tag in my apache .conf file (I think)

With all that config I have these errors in apache error.log

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
r->uri = /rapp/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/
redirected from r->uri = /rapp/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/
redirected from r->uri = /rapp/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/
redirected from r->uri = /rapp/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/
redirected from r->uri = /rapp/public/public/public/public/public/public/
redirected from r->uri = /rapp/public/public/public/public/public/
redirected from r->uri = /rapp/public/public/public/public/
redirected from r->uri = /rapp/public/public/public/
redirected from r->uri = /rapp/public/public/
redirected from r->uri = /rapp/public/
redirected from r->uri = /rapp/
```

I don't really understand why it search dor that much of public subfolder.

And finally, what I would like to do is:
When I go to `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/rapp/` it redirects me on my app in `/var/www/html/rapp/`.
So I want to have the subfolder where the app is installed, but not the `public/index.php` or `public/` part in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your rule's pattern `(.*)` also matches the destination path `/public/$1` and rewrites the destination to itself  in loop mode. You need to exclude the destination path in your RewriteRule to avoid the rewrite loop error.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rapp/
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Or you can also use a Condition to exclude the destination path

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rapp/
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} !/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, Seems it's working I know acces my app, but I have a problem with symfony.
The app try to access to /rapp/ on the application but that's just the subfolder the app is in.
And I don't find anywhere to specify in my app if it should have a folder prefix.